# LINUX & C : how to add notes to a file in c

Tags: c, linux

i want to add some informations to a file in C  under linux, can i save that information in its notes tab using C ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What?  What are "notes?"

Comment: You mean like a C source file?

Comment: I think regular C comments fits in the category of "notes."

Comment: @Jeff: I'm unclear if the OP wants to do this **in C** or **to a C source file**.  Either way, the question really needs to be improved.

Comment: @cdhowie: It really wasn't directed toward you sorry.  It was really for... um... From.ME.to.YOU.  Again, not really for you, but... _error: stackoverflow_  :)

Comment: @Jeff: Right, of course.  I think the general reaction to this question can be summed up as "uhm, wtf?"

Comment: I guess he means that he wants to add a tab in the program execution to offer the user to view the information about the program...

Comment: when you open the properties of an file with the file browser, on the last tab you have the "notes" tab. That one he wants to fill with a simple C program.

Comment: i think he means the "gnome" feature

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you want to set the attributes of a file (file properties that gets displayed when you see file properties from a GUI shell) from your C code. You may want to check out `*xattr` syscalls:
http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/listxattr.2.html 
http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/getxattr.2.html 
http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/setxattr.2.html 
Here's some info that you might be interested in:
https://superuser.com/questions/191385/saving-notes-against-a-file-on-linux